# How to get the accountId that is required to do a cloud build with nativescript?

Tags: nativescript

Currently the following command:

`tns cloud build android --accountId=<cannot find the account id assigned to our email>`

returns this line: `Invalid accountId index provided`

How could you get the correct **accountId** for your account?

(*note that we have already used `tns login` to login successfully*)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

'1' works for me.

> --accountId=1

Answer (score 5):

An interesting solution from pansila :) 
Still, if you want to build with your account ID, you should log in with `tns login` and then use the following command to get the ID

```
tns account
```

It will spawn information similar to the following

```
┌───┬──────────────────────────────────────┬────────────────┬──────────┐
│ # │ Id                                   │ Account        │ Type     │
│ 1 │ 000000-11111-2222222-555555          │ myaccount name │ personal │
└───┴──────────────────────────────────────┴────────────────┴──────────┘
```

So then you could make cloud build with

```
tns cloud accountId=000000-11111-2222222-555555
```